# BufferedReader default buffer size?

Tags: java, buffer, bufferedreader

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader%28java.io.Reader%29), `BufferedReader(Reader)` uses a default buffer size, while the second constructor, `BufferedReader(Reader, int)` allows the buffer size to be set.

> public BufferedReader(Reader in)
>
> Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses a default-sized input buffer.

However, the docs do not not mention what the default buffer size is.

**What is the default buffer size of a BufferedReader?**

Comment: [BufferedReader](http://ulibgcj.sourceforge.net/javadoc/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader(java.io.Reader))  might interest you

Comment: @Vulcan EJP gave you a wrong answer then. as said I've extraced the actual .jar containing BufferedReader and took a look at it. maybe it was other way for some years, or will be other way in future, but now it is stricctly specified to 8192 in the java.io.BufferedReader!!!

Comment: @Vulcan android was jsut an example of documentation. actual proof followed later. but since android also uses rt.jar, transitively the documentation is enough.

Comment: @IAM I did not give a wrong answer. I stated that it (a) is unspecified and (b) had been 4096 in the Oracle/Sun code for many years. They are free to change it at any time *because it is unspecified.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default buffer size is 8192 characters

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html

> ```
>  BufferedReader(Reader in)
> Constructs a new BufferedReader, providing in with a buffer of 8192 characters.
> ```

Besides this documentation, I've extraced the rt.jar archive, and decompiled the BufferedReader.class from java.io.* using [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), this is what I found in the class definition:

```
private static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192;
```

Comment: You may be right, but the official docs don't say that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: @7stud Take a look at link given in my comment.

Comment: @Smit, Back at ya: take a look at the oracle link in my comment.

Comment: @7stud I already looked at Javadoc API, and so my search ended me at that link. Anyhow lots of other forums says the same size and I ran your program and gave me `8192`

Comment: While the official docs do not mention this, I just took a look through the source code, and it is indeed 8192. Thanks.

Comment: This is the default in Android. OP didn't mention Android. It's different in the Oracle JDK. And not documented in either.

Comment: @EJP really? this was just an example of documentation. the real proof follows in the answer. as said, I've extracted the rt.jar, which contains default classes for the runtime, not jsut for the android. it contains the actual class for buffered reader. and it is 8192 by default there. may be it was different sometime, or will be different, but now it is specefied!

Comment: @IAM Yes really. It was different in Sun/Oracle for many years, and you cannot rely on what it may be in any specific release *because it is unspecified.* It can change tomorrow, which would invalidate your answer.

Comment: @IAM And 'present in the source code' does not mean 'specified'. *Of course* it is present in the source code. That's the *implementation.* The *Javadoc* is the specification, and it isn't present there. And the part in your quotation about 'a buffer of 8192 characters' **DOES NOT APPEAR IN YOUR LINK**. It is a fabrication.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't specified. On purpose. It's been 4096 for some years in the Sun/Oracle Java JDKs but don't rely on it.

Comment: It might be platform dependent, but it's [**8192** on current Android](https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jre_emul/android/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java#L44).

Comment: @Pevik Your link is to `BufferedInputStream`, and the question is about `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm sure</strike> I think it may be system/jvm dependent.  Run this program:

[What are the default buffer size for java.io.BufferedInputStream on old and exotic JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095269/what-are-the-default-buffer-size-for-java-io-bufferedinputstream-on-old-and-exot)

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class BufferSizeDetector extends BufferedInputStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferSizeDetector bsd = new BufferSizeDetector(null);

        System.err.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.err.println(bsd.getBufferSize());
    }

    public BufferSizeDetector(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public int getBufferSize() {
        return super.buf.length;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
1.6.0_45
8192
```

Comment: Interesting, but what assures that `BufferedReader` and `BufferedInputStream` have the same default buffer size?

Comment: @Vulcan, Good point. (Stupid BufferedReader class doesn't have a buf field).

Answer (score 1):

Ans is 8 KB.

1024 bytes * 8 = 8192 (8 KB)
refer class :  `java.io.BufferedReader`

```
private static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192;
```