# How BufferedInputStream requests data in chunks from OS

Tags: java, io, stream

I read this question : [Why is using BufferedInputStream to read a file byte by byte faster than using FileInputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600331/why-is-using-bufferedinputstream-to-read-a-file-byte-by-byte-faster-than-using-f/18600383) According to author `BufferedInputStream(BIS)` faster than `FileInputStream(FIS)` because when method `read()` is invoked in `FileInputStream` it always does system call using native API in order to fetch single byte, while `BufferedInputStream` does the same but it requires chunk of bytes from OS and stores them in local field called `buf` which is declared inside BIS class and then when `read()` is called BIS return byte from `buf` array.

I looked through the code of BIS ,specifically `read()` method and it doesn't clear for me when it happens,when BIS requires chunk of bytes instead of one. Method `read()` firstly checks `if (pos >= count)` If so it calls `fill()` method which firstly checks that buf is not full , if buf has space then method of InputStream is called `public int read(byte b[], int off, int len)` where b[] is our buffer , and inside of this method we can see that it makes system calls inside loop which is equal to `len` param .

```
for (; i < len ; i++) {
                c = read();
```

Did i miss something or both classes BIS and FIS will do the same amount of system calls in order to fetch each byte separately ?

Comment: The answer you linked to continued; *With a BufferedInputStream, the method delegates to an overloaded read() method that reads 8192 amount of bytes and buffers them until they are needed. It still returns only the single byte (but keeps the others in reserve).* It's worth noting that in most cases, your application will be IO bound. Because IO is slow.

Comment: A ByteBuffer which reads in 8196 (8k) chunks is faster.  A FileChannel with a 64k ByteBuffer will be even faster (in general).  Generally speaking, if you need speed and performance, use a bigger buffer for reading.

Comment: @markspace I know that it faster but I want to understand why , I want to know how BIS fetches optimize reading chunk of bytes instead of single byte even though I found that it does plenty old read() call in loop

Comment: The answer is "it's complex."  There are optimizations that occur, but they're specific and hard to predict.  For example, with higher "demand" in the application (i.e. a larger buffer) the OS will allocate more of its own resources to reading a file, and that speeds up file access.  Larger read-ahead buffers are a typical way to speed things up, but it's hard to make specific guess.  Basically, "it just is" and it's implementation dependent on other parts of the system why it works that way.

Comment: @markspace It means that I don't need BIS class because I just can use overloaded version of read method with my own byte array , Am I right ?

Comment: BufferedInputStream is code that somebody wrote already, don't re-invent the wheel.  If you need exactly the functionality it provides, just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place.

InputStream provides implementation of `int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` which indeed invokes `read()` in a loop. So if a concrete InputStream wrapped by BuffredInputStream does not override this method, then there will be no performance improvement. However, the question you linked talks specifically about FileInputStream which *does* override this method by invoking `native int readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len)`.

Comment: Thank you man , I completely forgot that this method could be overwritten  in FIS