# How to export results in Hana?

Tags: eclipse, export-to-csv, hana

Hello everyone I have extract problem in hana database.
In our system, there is a calculation view that I use in Hana and I want to export the result when I run this query in Eclipse.

I did research and saw functions like "extract into", but I think it extract data from the whole system and gives it in different formats.

Firstly I changed the default display result rule which is 1000 lines to 1 million rows. However, my query results returns around 900 thousand lines and when I try right click and export result, the system crashes.

I don't want to export the whole structure from database. We only need excel of some results with some conditions.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EXPORT INTO](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_CLOUD_DATABASE/c1d3f60099654ecfb3fe36ac93c121bb/6a6f59bbfbb64ade84d83d7f87789753.html?locale=en-US) statement, which works for tables and views. Als [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71878077/export-hana-sql-query-or-table-in-csv) maybe helpful.

Comment: but if i do this can i lose the data in the database? I dont want to change anything  in the database while exporting the results to csv. I saw this topic, but when I use export function, I thought my data was gone, correct me if im wrong please. @Mathias Kemeter

Comment: No, it definitely won't change the original data. As the documentation is saying: "Use the EXPORT INTO statement to export the data from a table or view into a single CSV or parquet file." That's what it does.